# ASP.NET how to access textbox within public method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access a TextBox within `GridView1` from a public method, however the value/string returned is null so a **null reference error is being created**.

How I can access the TextBox because I really need the value `inside` to do something with it.

C# code:

```
protected void txtOut_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inside = ((TextBox)GridView1.FindControl("txtForeName")).Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: You have only one textbox in the gridview?

Comment: This is an example of 1 textbox from many I want to access.

Comment: Normally gridviews have textboxes in their rows and every row has the same id of textbox. So you can not find single textbox directly using GridView.FindControl. You need to try find control from specific GridViewRow.

Comment: What should I do if I want to access any row?

Comment: `GridView.Rows[index]` that's how you access individual row of gridview.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
GridViewRow row = (sender as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
string inside = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtForeName")).Text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the sender to TextBox class.

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
```

So you can get the text from textBox instance by

```
string text = textBox.Text;
```